# What does $.getScript return, and what does it do to scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred, .when

I'm creating a plugin where I want to load a few scripts and for each of them run the function `plugin`.

I created a [set of tests/examples](https://repl.it/@abalter/What-does-getScript-pass-to-callback-or-then) (code below).

Questions:

1. AJAX passes in the usual `data, textStatus, jqxhr` set of arguments. But apparently also creates a scope where the `plugin` function is available. Can't find anything about this in the docs. More details/explanation please!
2. What the heck is the `this` that seems to be in scope?
3. The 3rd example where I run get script by mapping off of a list of script names works as expected.
4. Building a list of deferreds and then running with `when` acts strangely. I get no indication the functions have run (no output), and when I remove the delays, it always seems to finish first ("done" is printed ahead of everything else). Are the functions running? I tried adding an `alert` and it does not appear when I use `when`.

***index.js***

```
var script_names = ["one.js", "two.js", "three.js"];

function as_callback(script_name)
{
  console.log("plugin function run as callback");
  console.log(`$.getScript(${script_name}, (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => plugin());`);
  $.getScript(script_name, (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => plugin());
  console.log();
}

function from_this(script_name)
{
  console.log("plugin function referred to from 'this'");
  console.log(`$.getScript(${script_name}, (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => this.plugin());`);
  $.getScript(script_name, (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => this.plugin());
  console.log();
}

function with_map(script_names)
{
  console.log("with map");
  console.log("string_names: " + JSON.stringify(script_names));
  console.log(`
  script_names.map((x) => 
  {
    $.getScript(x, (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => plugin())
  });
  `);
  script_names.map((x) => 
  {
    $.getScript(x, (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => plugin())
  });
  console.log();
}

function with_push_and_when(script_names)
{
  console.log("build array of deferred and run with when");
  console.log(`
  var plugs = [];
  script_names.map(x => $.getScript(x, (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => plugs.push(plugin)));
  $.when(plugs).done(console.log("done"));
  `);
  var plugs = [];
  script_names.map(x => $.getScript(x, (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => plugs.push(plugin)));
  $.when(plugs).done(console.log("done"));
  console.log();
}

as_callback('one.js');

setTimeout("from_this('two.js')", 2000);

setTimeout("with_map(script_names)", 4000);

setTimeout("with_push_and_when(script_names)", 6000);

var plugs = [];
script_names.map(x => $.getScript(x, (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => plugs.push(plugin)));
setTimeout("console.log('run when in global scope');$.when(plugs).done(console.log('done'))", 8000);
```

***one.js***

```
var plugin = function()
{
  console.log("one.js\n\n");
  // alert("one");
  return "one";
}
```

***two.js***

```
var plugin = function()
{
  console.log("two.js\n\n");
  return "two";
}
```

***three.js***

```
var plugin = function()
{
  console.log("three.js\n\n");
  return "three";
}
```

***output***

```
plugin function run as callback
$.getScript(one.js, (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => plugin());

one.js


plugin function referred to from 'this'
$.getScript(two.js, (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => this.plugin());

two.js


with map
string_names: ["one.js","two.js","three.js"]

  script_names.map((x) => 
  {
    $.getScript(x, (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => plugin())
  });


two.js


three.js


one.js


build array of deferred and run with when

  var plugs = [];
  script_names.map(x => $.getScript(x, (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => plugs.push(plugin)));
  $.when(plugs).done(console.log("done"));

done

run when in global scope
done
```

**NOTE:**
I added the accepted answer to the *repl.it*.

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: Did you read the docs?

Comment: @Barmar -- That only works if you have a single JS file. I don't know how I would demonstrate loading external scripts in that environment.

Comment: "The script is executed in the global context, so it can refer to other variables and use jQuery functions. Included scripts can have some impact on the current page."

Comment: @epascarello Yes. I RTFM. I must be missing the part where it says what environment or scope is available in the callback context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The callback function runs in the global context, after the script has been loaded. Since the script defines the global variable `plugin`, it can be accessed from the callback function.
2. `$.getScript` doesn't set a specific context, so `this` will be the global `window` object. `this.plugin` is the same as `window.plugin`, which is the global variable.
3. That's correct.
4. `$.getScript` returns a promise, but you're not pushing them onto `plugs`, you're just pushing `plugin`.

Assign the result of `.map()` to `plugs` to get the correct array of promises.

```
var plugs = script_names.map(x => $.getScript(x, (data, textStatus, jqxhr) => plugin()));
$.when(plugs).done(console.log("done"));
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. That makes sense, and answer #4 is so obvious, I should have figured it out myself.